# Two perfect squares in a right triangle

Tags: number-theory, euclidean-geometry

Prove that there is no integer sided right triangle in which the lengths of two sides are simultaneously perfect squares

Comment: Split your proof into two cases: 1. Assume by contradiction that the two smaller sides are perfect squares, and show that the hypotenuse cannot be integer (in fact, it is probably irrational). 2. Assume by contradiction that the hypotenuse and one of the two smaller sides are perfect squares, and show that the other smaller side cannot be integer (in fact, it is probably irrational).

Comment: I believe [these](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat's_Last_Theorem#Proofs_for_specific_exponents) two [links](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_of_Fermat's_Last_Theorem_for_specific_exponents#n.C2.A0.3D.C2.A04) to be relevant.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that such a triangle exist, then there is a nontrivial integer solution of $$a^4+b^2=c^4\tag{1}$$
or of:
$$ a^4+b^4=c^2\tag{2} $$
that are essentially the case $n=4$ of the Fermat's last theorem. The impossibility of $(1)/(2)$ can be proved by using Fermat's descent and the fact that $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ (the ring of gaussian integers) is a unique factorization domain.

Comment: I think the equation should be $a^4+b^4=c^2$. $c$ is not necessarily a perfect square. (two of them are perfect squares.)